# UNIX: Use a single find command to search files larger than 4 MiB, then pipe the output to a sort command

Tags: linux

I currently have a question I am trying to answer below. Below is what I have come up with, but doesn't appear to be working:

```
find /usr/bin -type f -size +4194304c | sort -n
```

Am I on the right track with the above?

Question:
Use a single find command to search for all files larger than 4 MiB in
/usr/bin, printing the listing in a long format. Pipe this output to a sort command
which will sort the list from largest to smallest

Comment: It does appear to be sorting, however I'm not sure if it's actually sorting from largest file size to smallest. Also adding -h doesn't add any file sizes in the output for me to actually verify this.

Answer (score 3):

I'd fiddle with for -printf command line switch, sth like this:

`find YOUR_CONDITION_HERE -printf '%s %p\n' | sort -n`: %s stands for size in bytes, %p for file name.
You can trim the sizes later, e.g. using `cut`, e.g.:

`find -type f -size +4194304c -printf '%s %p\n' | sort -n | cut -f 2 -d ' '`
But given the fact you need the long list format, I guess you'll be adding more fields to printf's argument.

Related topic: https://superuser.com/questions/294161/unix-linux-find-and-sort-by-date-modified

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track, but the `find` command will only output the name of the file, not it's size. This is why `sort` will sort them alphabetically.

To sort by size, you can output the file list and then pass it to `ls` with `xargs` like this:

```
find /usr/bin -type f -size +4194304c | xargs ls -S
```

If you want `ls` to output the file list on a single column, you can replace the `-S` with `-S1`. The command would become:

```
find /usr/bin -type f -size +4194304c | xargs ls -S1
```

To make your command resistant to all filenames, I would suggest using `-print0` (it will separate paths with the null character which is the only one that cannot appear in a filename in Linux). The command would become:

```
find /usr/bin -type f -size +4194304c -print0 | xargs -0 ls -S1
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also try

```
find /usr/bin -type f -size +4194304c -ls | sort -n -k7
```

and if you want the results reversed then try

```
find /usr/bin -type f -size +4194304c -ls | sort -r -n -k7
```

Or another option

```
find /usr/bin -type f -size +4194304c -exec ls -lSd {} +
```